# iPhone app launch in landscape mode. Why the obscure warning?

Tags: iphone

I want to launch my app in landscape mode and I am following the steps describe here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2009/tn2244.html

To summerize:

In my ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

In my Info.plist:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

Upon launch on either simulator or device I get this message:

Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.

Huh?

Could someone please explain what this means and provide me with the steps to resolve it.

Cheers,

Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this methods:

– willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Your ViewController has only one of them ? Try to comment it. Or add the second.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for this. Besides being a bit obscure these have got to be some of the longest method names I've ever seen ;-). Can you tell I'm a ole C hacker. Cheers. Thanks.